# select by columns multiple criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this db structure

[image: db structure]

and this is my joined tables [image: rawsql and data] (sample data)

i want to filter when (`key` = 'price' and `value` > 4000) and (`key` = 'top-speed' and `value` > 200)

thanks for help)

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text (i.e. no images, no links.)

Comment: Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: thanks but i can't post image without link

Comment: Exactly, no images, no links - just properly formatted text! (Make it possible for us to copy-and-paste.) https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: use the `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    car.id,
    car.name,
    key,
    value
FROM
    car                       c
    LEFT JOIN car_specification_value   csv ON c.id = csv.car_id
    LEFT JOIN specification             s ON csv.specification_id = s.id
WHERE
    s.key = 'price'
    AND csv.value > 4000
    AND s.key = 'top-speed'
    AND csv.value > 200;
```

A common practice is giving aliases to your tables so the join conditions can be determined in a shorter way.

Comment: if i use `and` nothing returned (

Answer (score 0):

One method uses aggregation:

```
select csv.car_id
from car_specification_value csv
where (csv.key = 'price' and (csv.value + 0) > 4000) and
      (csv.key = 'top-speed' and (csv.value + 0) > 200)
group by csv.car_id
having count(distinct csv.key) = 2;  -- both match
```

Note the `+ 0`.  This uses implicit conversion to change the value to a number, so it can be properly compared to a number.  One challenge of key/value data structures is that all the values are strings, and that is tricky for other data types.